# ReIndex a Pandas DataFrame using sum as the fill method

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames - one with a daily index and one with an irregular index. I'd like to sample the daily to the irregular, but use a **sum** as the `fill` method.

For example,

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2018-03-10', periods=10))
df0['dat'] = 1

# df1 has "missing" days
df1 = df0.iloc[[0,3,4,6,9]]

df0 = df0.reindex(df1, method='sum') # NOT A REAL METHOD
```

And the result I'm looking for in `df0` is:

```
2018-03-10 1 
2018-03-13 3  # sum of indices 1 and 2 and 3
2018-03-14 1
2018-03-16 2  # sum of 5 and 6
2018-03-19 3  # sum of 7, 8, and 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create groups for aggregate `sum` using [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) with `reindex` and back and forward filling `NAN`s:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2018-03-10', periods=12))
df0['dat'] = 1

a = df1.index.to_series().reindex(df0.index).bfill().ffill()
print (a)
2018-03-10   2018-03-10
2018-03-11   2018-03-13
2018-03-12   2018-03-13
2018-03-13   2018-03-13
2018-03-14   2018-03-14
2018-03-15   2018-03-16
2018-03-16   2018-03-16
2018-03-17   2018-03-19
2018-03-18   2018-03-19
2018-03-19   2018-03-19
2018-03-20   2018-03-19 #<-replace last NaNs by ffill()
2018-03-21   2018-03-19 #<-replace last NaNs by ffill()
Freq: D, dtype: datetime64[ns]

fin = df0.groupby(a).sum()
print (fin)
            dat
2018-03-10    1
2018-03-13    3
2018-03-14    1
2018-03-16    2
2018-03-19    5
```

Comment: Perhaps my example was too simple. In reality my index is `datetime64[ns]`, not `np.arange(10)`. I've edited the question to show this.

Comment: @mankoff - What is expected output if `df0 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2018-03-10', periods=12))` ?

Comment: That seems to work. Thank you! Sorry that my first MWE was to M to be a good E.

Comment: @mankoff - No problem, I also forget for possible `NaN`s in last values :) Nice weekend!

Comment: FYI in my case I will leave off the `ffill()`. The value for `2018-03-19` should be `3` - the sum of the 17th, 18th, and 19th.

Comment: Sorry, i changed period to `12`